# Reading a spreadsheetl file from fileupload control into filestream

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, filestream

I am trying to find the best way of selecting an excel spreadsheet (xls and xlsx) using a fileupload control and then parsing it with filestream object and then populating a dataset.

This is my code so far which does the job but how it differs is I am saving the excel spreadsheet to a folder in my solution then querying the data using Microsoft ACE OLEDB connection.

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectingString = "";
        if (ctrlFileUpload.HasFile)
        {
            string fileName =
                Path.GetFileName(ctrlFileUpload.PostedFile.FileName);

            string fileExtension =
                Path.GetExtension(ctrlFileUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
                //Path.GetExtension(ctrlFileUpload.PostedFile.ContentType);

            string fileLocation =
                Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + fileName);
            ctrlFileUpload.SaveAs(fileLocation);

            // Check whether file extension is xls or xslx
            if (fileExtension == ".xls")
            {
                connectingString =
                    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +
                    fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=2\"";
            }

            else if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
            {
                connectingString =
                    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                    fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=2\"";
            }

            // Create OleDb Connection and OleD Command
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectingString))
            {
                try
                {
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                    //DataTable dtExcelRecords = new DataTable();
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    con.Open();
                    DataTable dtExcelSheetName = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

                    string getExcelSheetName = dtExcelSheetName.Rows[0]["Table_Name"].ToString();
                    cmd.CommandText = "Select * FROM [" + getExcelSheetName + "]";
                    dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    //dAdapter.Fill(dtExcelRecords);
                    dAdapter.Fill(ds);
                    //GridView1.DataSource = dtExcelRecords;
                    //GridView1.DataBind();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }

        }
    }
```

So to summarise I want to read the data in a spreadsheet and then bind it to a dataset but without saving the file to a physical path.

Is there a cleaner way of writing this code that I am missing. Thanks!!

Comment: Is Chandra one of your colleagues? http://stackoverflow.com/q/12420310/284240

Comment: Lol no he is not but I will take a look at that link. Thanks!

Comment: Are there not any solutions which can be used without having to download a custom class library?

Answer (score 0):

I think it not possible to get data without save file to your server

If you can't save uploded file how can you give `Data Source` to your oleDbConnection string ??

you can delete file after finish this execution if you don't want to keep the file.

you can also refer this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/12420416/284240

Comment: That was the suggestion that I made to my manager but he thought that reading the file using filestream would be better.