# How do I add ExcelPackage to my C# project to read an uploaded xls file?

Tags: c#, excel, reference, xls

I am trying to write a script that reads a xls file that the user uploaded on a page.  The input looks like this:

```
<body>
    <form id="uploadForm" runat="server">
        <div>
            <input type="file" id="UpdateFile" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="submitFile" Text="Submit" OnClick="SubmitButton_Click"/>
        </div>
    </form>
    <h3 id="message" runat="server"></h3>
</body>
```

---

```
protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (UpdateFile.PostedFile != null)
    {
        var file = UpdateFile.PostedFile;
        ....
```

I'm trying to figure out how to read this file line by line. I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420310/read-an-excel-file-uploaded-using-fileupload-control-without-saving-it-on-the-se) suggesting using ExcelPackage but I can't figure out how to add ExcelPackage to my project. I used the NuGet package manager to add ExcelPackage to my project but my code isn't recognizing it, ExcelPackage isn't showing up in my references even though I added it through NuGet.

Comment: you could just read it into a dataset and then loop through line by line

Comment: Are you asking what `using` statement you should be using?

Comment: yeah pretty much. I added `using ExcelPackage` but it wasn't recognized

Answer (score 0):

```
DataSet ds= new DataSet();

using (OleDbConnection conn= new OleDbConnection(connStr))
{
 OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);

    conn.Open();
   using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
   {
       da.Fill(ds);
   }

}
```

then you can loop through your dataset:

```
foreach(DatRow dr in ds.Table[0].Rows)
{


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Install-Package EPPlus for this u need Tool----->Library----->package console